# Google Analytics tracking not installed

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics is saying that:

> Status: Tracking Not Installed

on my site, when (as far as I can tell) I have put the tracking code in the [site](http://todddavies.co.uk). What do I need to do to get Google Analytics to detect the tracking script is there on my site.

Comment: Have you verified ownership of your domain? Make sure that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about that. Sometimes the Google Analytics Dashboard takes a while to update the status, while in fact the tracking is already working. To be sure, go to Real-Time-Tracking in your Google Analytics Dashboard and see if the traffic updates while surfing your website.

From the sourcecode of your site, the tracking snippet seems to be installed correctly.

[image: Universal Tracking Installed]

Answer (score 0):

You must put the Google Analytics script just before the closing `</head>` tag, not at the end of your webpage.

For more information, read [Google guidelines](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en) to install Google Analytics on your website.